# How to ensure a table of Postgres range types totally cover a range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, aggregate-functions

I have a table of Postgres `numrange` types, which I'm calling `buckets`. The ranges on each of these buckets can be any size, but altogether they need to cover a certain range ([0 to 2<sup>160</sup>], in my case).

Currently, I have a custom aggregation function that uses `+`, which is overloaded for `numrange + numrange` (`SUM` is not implemented for ranges). The rows need to be sorted before aggregation, so that the pieces stay contiguous as they are accumulated. Postgres's `CREATE AGGREGATE` statement allows for the `SORTOP` argument, and I provide the `<` operator, which is [implemented for ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

My problem is that when I implement this aggregator like in my code examples below, I get this error:

> `ERROR 42883 (undefined_function) operator does not exist: numrange < numrange`

If I remove `SORTOP`, this aggregator does work in the trivial case (two buckets that are side-by-side), but give more buckets, it predictably doesn't work:

> `ERROR 22000 (data_exception) result of range union would not be contiguous`

I'm aware that I could get this error even if the sort operator does work, if my data is not actually contiguous, but I'm fine getting this error in that case.

Here's what I'm working with right now that gives me the first error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION numrange_accum_sfunc(numrange, numrange)
RETURNS numrange AS
$$
        SELECT $1 + $2;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STRICT;

CREATE AGGREGATE numrange_accum(numrange)
(
  STYPE = numrange,
  SFUNC = numrange_accum_sfunc,
  SORTOP = <
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enforce_bucket_coverage() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    bucket_range numrange := numrange(0,0);
BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE buckets IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

    SELECT numrange_accum(range)
    FROM buckets
    INTO bucket_range;

    IF bucket_range <> numrange(0,1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542977) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Bucket ranges must completely cover the range from 0 to 2^160 (inclusive). Coverage after inserting was %', bucket_range;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: For those curious why I'm trying to cover such a huge range of numbers: This is the simplest way I found to create ranges for twenty-byte binary IDs. My application layer is converting between these binary IDs and integers for storage, since I do need to separate these IDs into different buckets organized this way. It's for a BitTorrent distributed hash table. http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can specify an order when you're calling an aggregate function, like this:

```
SELECT numrange_accum(range order by lower(range))
FROM buckets
INTO bucket_range;
```

This orders the input before passing it into the accumulator.